# Recursive function works only without a class, but not with class

Tags: php, file, oop, directory, php-7

I have a php code which performs directory/file listing. However, it does not work when called by object.

**Following Code Works :**

```
function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()){
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $key => $value){
    $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
    if(!is_dir($path)) {
        $results[] = $path;
    } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {
        getDirContents($path, $results);
        $results[] = $path;
    }
}
// print_r($results);
return $results;
}

var_dump(getDirContents('C:\xampp\htdocs\skillup\d4a1'));
```

**The following code DOES NOT work :**

```
class Dira {
function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()){
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $key => $value){
    $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
    if(!is_dir($path)) {
        $results[] = $path;
    } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {
        getDirContents($path, $results);
        $results[] = $path;
    }
}
// print_r($results);
return $results;
}
```

}

```
$obj = new Dira;
$arr = array();
var_dump($obj->getDirContents('C:\xampp\htdocs\skillup\d4a1'));
```

Comment: Is that your whole code ?

Comment: Because you don't know what is `$this`?

Comment: yes, but apparently it works with object only if there are no sub-directories inside the given path of the directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in your method, your method calls itself recursively via:

```
getDirContents();
```

but should do so like (in your Dira class):

```
$this->getDirContents();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursive function `getDirContents()` but when you call it again you are missing `$this` .

Try Below Example :

```
class abc{
    public function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()){ 
    $files = scandir($dir);

        foreach($files as $key => $value){
            $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
            if(!is_dir($path)) {
                $results[] = $path;
            } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {
                $this->getDirContents($path, $results);
                $results[] = $path;
            }
        }
    return $results;
    }
}
$res = new abc();
$re = $res->getDirContents('YOUR PATH');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($re);
```